# How can the ipython notebook store inline images as compressed SVGs?

Tags: svg, ipython

One can set the default file-format to use for inline images in ipython by including something like the following in a cell:

```
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
```

This results in SVG being used to store and display inline images.

**I would like to know if it is possible to make ipython store these images as *compressed* rather than uncompressed SVGs.**

If it is possible, what must be done to make it happen?